# Conflict of Controllers in MVC PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am new to PHP. I am developing an application using `MVC` in PHP. I think I still have some questions roaming around my head about MVC.

In `MVC`(please correct me if I'm wrong), `MODEL` will have the data(or gets the data from `DB`) and `VIEW` will display it. My `MODEL` classes read data from the `DB` and I need to display that data in the `VIEW`.

My question is, how can I do that??
How can `MODEL`(which is in PHP) pass the data to the `VIEW`(which is in `HTML`) and how can I apply the `CSS` styles to that data.

For Example : The user searches for a patient, `Controller` will take the `patient_id` from the user and passes it to the `MODEL`, `MODEL` then, get the details from the `DB`. now, how can `MODEL` present these details in a pretty table format in the `VIEW`?

Comment: It's just PHP, not `PHP`, no need for all that unusual formatting.

Comment: `VIEWs` are *not* necessarily HTML. They can be PHP, XML, or whatever you want. In fact, most frameworks use a templating engine to render the views.

Comment: In most MVC type systems there's a separation of concerns and also an implied hierarchy. Models do not send anything to views, instead views may ask the model for data if permitted. Some systems have the controller act as a strict intermediary, nothing the view gets comes from anywhere but the controller.

Comment: @tadman Arguably none of the supposed `code spans` in the `question` are `actually` code.`.`.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial which builds an MVC application from the ground up - http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/

Comment: The Controller mediates between the Model and the View layer. The Controller calls the Model layer, gets the data and passes the "ViewData" to the View layer (template engine). Then the controller returns the rendered response.

Comment: @DanielO controllers do not mediate or render, view is not a template engine. Stop spreading the disinformation, that you have learned from some crappy framework.

Comment: @tereško Thanks for the feedback. I didn't mean it like that. I don't think you interpreted my answer correctly.

Comment: @waterloomatt that tutorial has nothing to do with MVC. Instead it is propagating **bad practices**. Stop harming newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this diagram and can't add it in comments, but i hope it will give you a better sense on how MVC works

[image]

so basically you don't send info from MODEL to VIEW but from MODEL to CONTROLLER and then to VIEW

Comment: That's just one interpretation of the MVC pattern where the controller acts as a strict intermediary. In other systems like Rails, it's a lot more lax and the view will directly interface with models if necessary.

Comment: he specified PHP and i was assuming he will be using one of the popular frameworks like Laravel or Zend framework that works as the diagram above, however your point is perfectly valid :)

Comment: Yeah. Im just saying that if your view allows you to run arbitrary code, which many systems do permit, the view can do all sorts of things, some of which might not fit on this neat diagram. In that case the controller acts as a view initiator, not a strict gatekeeper. On platforms like iOS the views aren't really able to do anything at all, the controller must directly "control" them.

Comment: would u care to elaborate on it ?

Comment: Controller's role is to alter the state of the model layer. It is NOT a traffic manager between manager. The view is responsible for creating a representation of the new model's state, when the model layer has been changed. It is called a "triad" not a "line": https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/MVC-Process.svg

Comment: thx for that, i am aware of the wikipedia diagram, however i've never use it like that in Laravel or Zend Framework, just in the way seen on my diagram so i've post only what i've used, if is good or bad i guess it's up for debate :)

Comment: Laravel has nothing to do with MVC, I would not recommend trying to hold it up as an example of anything. I am not sure about ZF2. And that is besides the point. **Frameworks do not implement MVC**. Your code does (or, as it might be - doesn't).

Comment: Then it is just another Rails-clone, that uses "MVC" for marketing.

Comment: of course, frameworks don't implement MVC, but it makes it easier for you than starting from scratch, anyways thank you for your input, i really appreciate it! :)

Comment: i as actually doing that now :)